# lastLocation returns an old location

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to retrieve the location every 10 seconds. The problem is that the location sometimes is `null`, and sometimes gives back an old location. When I update the location in my emulator it is not updating live.

Code to get location:

```
 fun checkLocation() {
        
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 1)
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 1)
                }
            }


            return
        }

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
                    println("LOCATION " + location?.latitude + ", " + location?.longitude);
                }
    }
```

PermissionCheck:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            1 -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ===
                                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Timer executed in my `onCreate`:

```
val timer = object: CountDownTimer(18000000, 10000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                checkLocation();
            }
            override fun onFinish() {}
        }
        timer.start()
```

Output:

```
I/System.out: LOCATION 37.4219752, -122.0839923
```

While my new location is somewhere totally else. Even after restarting the app. Is there a way to request the app/device to get the new location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rely on `lastLocation` completely , `lastLocation` can be null

Also `lastLocation` will return the device last known location so it will not  update as the device location updates until and unless some other app is requesting location (like google map)

`lastLocation` literally means that we are not requesting for new Location, instead we are using location which are requested by other apps, so the lastLocation can be null or old

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

So Instead of relying on `lastLocation` use `requestLocationUpdates`, using which you can set the time interval like after how much time you want to receive the new location, so you don't have to implement `CountDownTimer`

I think for your case `requestLocationUpdates` will be the best option

Read below docs for how to request Location updates

https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates

Answer (score 2):

This is in Addition to @Shobhith's Answer above.

When working with the emulator it doesn't update the location immediately thus the reason for returning the old location.

To get around this you need to *set the location in the emulator*

[image]

Then open Map Application (already installed in the emulator) and press the `My Location Button` *to force the emulator to update the location*.

[image]